# CSS Block resets after rotation (transform)

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to make certain image which rotates around when the mouse is hovering the object, If I do this rotation on the Y axis everything works fine, however when I do this on the X axis everything tends to fail like the example below.

EDIT: I'm using Chrome, and now looking further on this, Internet explorer doesn't even show the red face at all.

```css
.card-container {
  height: 150px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Correct version (Y version):

```css
.card-container {
  height: 150px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems a correct rotation along the x axis to me

Comment: The image resets to the green side when the animation is complete

Comment: This is how the transition works: if you lose the :hover state you have a transition to the initial state

Comment: But it returns to green when the mouse is on the object..

Comment: @Fabrizio Then why the difference in behavior between rotateX and rotateY?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan check both versions now, the first one is incorrect, and the second one is correct.. but over the wrong axis.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 32.0.2 and they both behave in the same way: they stay red until I move the mouse outside the box.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I'm using chrome, the first one shows the green face after the animation is done, and the second one works fine.. and on IE it doesn't even show the back face.

Comment: Confirmed in chrome, seems like a browser bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove  `transform: rotateX(180deg);` from `.card .back` it properly works also on Chrome

```css
.card-container {
  height: 150px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .back {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code does the colors inverted, but I'll find a workaround for that, Thanks! i'll mark it as an awnser as soon as I am allowed to do that.